# Home dir of ftp user in /var/www

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ftp, selinux, vsftpd

I am trying to make a web server with Centos 7, I am trying to give access to a certain user in the `/var/www` dir via ftp making that dir his home directory. I use `vsftpd`; this is my config file:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
pasv_enable=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

I created the home dir of the user in `/var/www/user` and I have tried to give the user 775 permissions but it does not work. I added the user to the `apache` and `ftp` group but that didn't help either.

The only way that I got it working is changing seLinux param `allow_ftpd_full_access` to on but I don't think this is a good practice. The param `ftp_home_dir` doesn't exist, but I found `tftp_home_dir`. I don't know if it the same. I changed it to on but it did nothing..

How can I get this to work?
Thank you all!

Comment: tftp and ftp are not the same

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know they are not the same, but I do not know how to achive this. Any idea what I do wrong?